# JavaScript button can only be clicked once

Tags: javascript

I'm building something like currency converter app with JS and have a problem with swaping the currencies.

When I press on the swap button the elements swap like they should, but when I press on the swap button again nothing happens, I can't switch back.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    var changeCurr = document.getElementById("swap-currency");

    function swap() {
        var leftBtn = document.getElementById("konverter-btn-left");
        var rightBtn = document.getElementById("konverter-btn-right");
        var leftImg = document.getElementById("konverter-img-left");
        var rightImg = document.getElementById("konverter-img-right");

        if (leftBtn.textContent = "EUR") {
            leftBtn.innerHTML = "USD " + '<span class="caret"></span>';
            rightBtn.innerHTML = "EUR " + '<span class="caret"></span>';
            leftImg.src = "assets/img/usa-flag.png";
            rightImg.src = "assets/img/eu-flag.jpg";
        } else if (leftBtn.textContent = "USD") {
            leftBtn.textContent = "EUR " +  + '<span class="caret"></span>';
            rightBtn.textContent = "USD " + '<span class="caret"></span>';
            leftImg.src = "assets/img/eu-flag.png";
            rightImg.src = "assets/img/usa-flag.jpg";
        }
    }
    changeCurr.addEventListener("click", swap);
</script>
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: `if (leftBtn.textContent = "EUR") {`  is an assignment, not a comparison. Use `==` or `===`.

Comment: Yeah, that should work, but it does not

Comment: `else if (leftBtn.textContent = "USD") {` is also an assignment, not a comparison. Use again `==` or `===`

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are mistaking the `=` with `==` and `===` operator.

We have provided an answer to your question in the comments.

You can further check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) for an explanation about the differences.

In short, `==` is abstract comparison and sometimes may give you unwanted results. As an example consider

```
"0" == 0  // evaluates to true
```

which evaluates to true, since the values are implicitly converted to have the same types.

in `===` on the other hand, neither value is implicitly converted and if the values have different types, they are considered unequal.

"0" === 0 // evaluates to false

Good luck.